Infinite-dimensional cube $[0,1]^\mathbb N$ compact/complete under certain metrics?
Consider the infinite-dimensional cube $[0,1]^\mathbb N := \{ (x_i)_{i=1}^\infty \ | \ 0 \le x_i \le 1 \ \forall i \}.$ This space can be equipped with certain metrics. Below are two of them.

$d_\infty(x,y) := \sup\limits_{i \in \mathbb N} |x_i - y_i|$
$d(x,y) := \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \dfrac{|x_i - y_i|}{2^i}$

My questions are:

Is $[0,1]^\mathbb N$ compact w.r.t to the metric $d_\infty$?
Is $[0,1]^\mathbb N$ compact w.r.t to the metric $d$?
Is $\left( [0,1]^\mathbb N , d_\infty \right)$ a complete metric space?
Is $\left( [0,1]^\mathbb N , d \right)$ a complete metric space?

My progress:
For the first one, I think the answer is "No" because compactness is equivalent to the Bolzano-Weierstrass property (every sequence has a convergent subsequence). However, the sequence $(e_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ that consists of the elements of the orthonormal basis does not have a convergent subsequence.
The other three were not as straightforward... Any help is appreciated.
P.S: This is not a homework or anything like that.

To my knowledge, the Heine-Borel property is that closed bounded subsets are compact, whereas what you're referring to is usually called "sequential compactness".

My apologies, I should've said "Bolzano-Weierstrass property". Edited.

You first counter-example works. For the third question, your space is indeed complete. Consider a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)_{n \geqslant 0}$ with respect to $d_\infty$. For all $n,m,i$, we have $|x_{n,i} - x_{m,i}| \leqslant d_\infty(x_n,x_m) \rightarrow 0$ hence, since $\mathbb{R}$ is complete, each $(x_{n,i})$ converges toward some real number $l_i$. Let us show that $x_n \rightarrow l$ for $d_\infty$.
Let $\varepsilon > 0$. By the Cauchy sequence property, for all $n,m$ greater than some given $n_0$ depending only on $\varepsilon$, $d_\infty(x_n,x_m) \leqslant \varepsilon$. Therefore, for all $i$, $|x_{n,i} - x_{m,i}| \leqslant \varepsilon$. For $n \geqslant n_0$ fixed and $m \rightarrow +\infty$, we obtain that $|x_{n,i} - l_i| \leqslant \varepsilon$. It is true for all $i$ so $d_\infty(x_n,l) \leqslant \varepsilon$ when $n \geqslant n_0$. It is the wanted convergence result.
For the other two question, recall that any metric space is compact if and only if it is complete and pre-compact. Let us prove that $([0,1]^{\mathbb{N}},d)$ is pre-compact. Indeed, if $\varepsilon > 0$, set $N$ large enough so
$$
\sum_{i \geqslant N} \frac{1}{2^i} < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.
$$
Cover the compact space $([0,1]^N,d)$ with a finite union of balls $(B_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A}$ of radius $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Let for all $\alpha$, $B_\alpha'$ be the ball of same centre than $B_\alpha$ but of radius $\varepsilon$. Then, if $x \in [0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$, let,
$$
y_i = \mathbf{1}_{i \leqslant N - 1}x_i.
$$
Then, $y \in [0,1]^N$ is in one of the $B_\alpha$ and $d(x,y) \leqslant \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ thus $x \in B_\alpha'$. It proves the pre-compactness.
For the completeness, notice that the map,
$$
\iota : \left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
([0,1]^{\mathbb{N}},d) & \rightarrow & (l^1(\mathbb{N}),\|\cdot\|_{l^1})\\
x & \mapsto & \left(\frac{x_i}{2^i}\right)
\end{array}\right.,
$$
is a closed embedding and an isometry onto its image. By completeness of $l^1(\mathbb{N})$ and completeness of the closed subset of a complete space, $([0,1]^{\mathbb{N}},d)$ is complete.
Notice that the same argument holds to prove the completeness of $([0,1]^{\mathbb{N}},d_\infty)$, but by sending $x \mapsto x$ and using the infinite norm in the space of arrival ($(l^\infty(\mathbb{N}),\|\cdot\|_{l^\infty})$ is complete too).
